# iOS How can I dynamic change the PageControl color when change the page?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 3 page - A ViewController, B ViewController and C ViewController.

And A PageViewController control there horizontal scroll.

PagesViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.aVC = [self.storyboard
       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AViewController"];
     self.bVC = [self.storyboard
            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BViewController"];
     self.cVC = [self.storyboard
            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CViewController"];

     self.delegate = self;
     self.dataSource = self;

     self.allViewControllers = @[self.aVC,self.bVC
                            ,self.cVC];

     [self setViewControllers:@[self.aVC]
               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                animated:NO completion:nil];

     _pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];

 }
```

I want to change the _pageControl color when I scroll to A VC , B VC and C VC.

So I put the code in

```
 -(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:
 (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
 {

     NSLog(@"%@",pageViewController.viewControllers[0]);
     for( int i = 0 ; i< self.allViewControllers.count ; i++ )
     {
         if( pageViewController.viewControllers[0] == self.allViewControllers[i])
         {
             if( i ==0 )
             {
                 _pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
             }
             else if( i ==1)
             {
                 _pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
             }
             else
             {
                 _pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
             }
             NSLog(@"return index:%d", i);
             return i;
         }
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

But the page control was not change the color.

I try to put below the code in the **viewDidLoad**, it will change color at all the view controller.

```
 _pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But now I want to change the pageControl color when I scroll to different UIViewController.

**How can I do? or How can I refresh the pageControl color?**

Because now the color always black.

I offer others delegate method about the PageViewController:

```
 -(UIViewController*) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

{

```
NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.allViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
if( currentIndex == 0 )
{
    return nil;
}
currentIndex--;


     return [self.allViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
 }

 -(UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
     NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.allViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];


     NSLog(@"after currentIndex:%ld",currentIndex);
     currentIndex++;

if( currentIndex == [self.allViewControllers count])
{
    return nil;
}

     return [self.allViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
 }


 -(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:
 (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
 {
     return self.allViewControllers.count;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad:` method,

instead of:

```
_pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
```

use:

```
NSArray *subviews = self.view.subviews;
_pageControl = nil;
for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
    if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
        _pageControl = (UIPageControl *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
```

=====

EDIT:

For your specific project, you're not getting the _pageControl (it's returning nil) because the Storyboard has not completed instantiating your view controller in the viewDidLoad.  I thought it would need to go in viewDidAppear:animated, but that didn't work either, so I cheated by delaying requesting it for 0.2 milliseconds.

In your viewDidLoad, put this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(findPageControl) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2f];
```

Then, add this method:

```
- (void) findPageControl {
    NSArray *subviews = self.view.subviews;
    _pageControl = nil;
    for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
        if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
            _pageControl = (UIPageControl *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
    [self changePage:0];
}
```

In your viewControllerAfterViewController method, I added this right after the NSUInteger currentIndex = line:

```
[self changePage:currentIndex];
```

That seems to have made it work.  Now, you could add an animation in your changePage method to make the transition seem a little smoother.

Also, when debugging, this is what I did:

I added a breakpoint on the _pageControl = line, so I could check and see what was happening.  When I saw it was nil, that told me that it wasn't being set properly.  Look in the debug area, and you can see what I printed out ("po") to see what values existed -- and why there was no UIPageControl.  If you do the same after the changes I list above, you'll see that this is now found and set.

[image]

Comment: This runs through all of the subviews and finds the UIPageControl reference that you need to then change the background (or whatever you would like).

Comment: Hi, the method can't use in the UIPageViewController. I use the method, then I try to _pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; in the viewDidLoad. Or I try to add - (void) changePage:(NSInteger) currentPage; in the  pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController; There are not change any pagecontrol color. @@?

Comment: I used this project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/iecfyqffudzyybp/PageViewControllerExample.zip?dl=0

Comment: I made my change above, and modified the viewControllerBeforeViewController (the line right before the return) to be: pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: Hello, I post my test project.https://www.dropbox.com/s/zho38t2idmhitf3/UIPageControlColor.zip?dl=0

Comment: Can you see where the problem in my code? I am using storyboard to build.

Comment: And I had use your code to change the color, the color are not changed.

Comment: At the first, I want  to thank you detail explain my question. Then I found a question, If I set the _pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  It will show black, not the the pages color. Have possible transparent show the page controller color? Thank you again.

Comment: Setting it to clearColor shows through to the main self background (which is black).  Setting self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; does nothing, because the parent window is backed with black. Each of your viewControllers will need to be extended to cover that bar, for that to work, and I believe that might cause them to cover over the page control.

Comment: umm,umm. I think new a pagecontrol add to the view, like your first answer. that maybe easier to set the backgroundcolor.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, just with a pageControl in a UIViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40)];
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 6;
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.view addSubview:pageControl];
}

- (void) changePage:(UIPageControl *)page {
    NSInteger currentPage = page.currentPage;
    switch (currentPage) {
        case 0:
            pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        case 1:
            pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;
        case 2:
            pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi , If I use the UIPageViewController , How can I do?

Comment: I posted that fix as well, but thought I should leave this one in case someone has the same problem, but with a UIPageControl.